# Qt QWebPage printing - text cut off

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have the following Qt code that loads a local html file and prints it using the installed PDFCreator. When printing to PDFCreator the text is cut off at the right and only printed on the first page. Subsequent pages are without text just filled with the background color.

When using `QPrinter::PdfFormat` as output Format and setting a file path a PDF file is successfully generated and the content is showing correctly. I'm using Qt 5.4.

Do I need to set special parameters for the printer or is this still a Qt bug (there was one reported for Qt 5.0).

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWebPage>
#include <QWebFrame>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QPrinter>

class Task : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Task(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {}

public slots:
    void run()
    {
        QFileInfo fileInfo("test.html");
        QUrl url = QUrl::fromLocalFile(fileInfo.absoluteFilePath());
        connect(&page, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), this, SLOT(print()));
        page.mainFrame()->load(url);
    }

    void print()
    {
        QPrinter printer;
        printer.setPrinterName("PDFCreator");
        printer.setPaperSize(QPrinter::A4);

#ifdef PRINT_TO_PDF
        printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
        printer.setOutputFileName("output.pdf");
#endif
        page.mainFrame()->print(&printer);

        emit finished();
    }

signals:
    void finished();

private:
    QWebPage page;
};

#include "main.moc"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // Task parented to the application so that it
    // will be deleted by the application.
    Task *task = new Task(&app);

    // This will cause the application to exit when
    // the task signals finished.    
    QObject::connect(task, SIGNAL(finished()), &app, SLOT(quit()));

    // This will run the task from the application event loop.
    QTimer::singleShot(0, task, SLOT(run()));

    return app.exec();
}
```